# Java - listen for system safe paste command

Tags: java, swing, paste, listen

I need to fire an event when the user pastes text into my program, specifically a JTextArea. Is there a system independent method for detecting a paste command? I've been looking around, but can't seem to find a listener for this purpose. I'd settle for a non-system safe workaround, but I was hoping there would be a universal method for this.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "system independent"?

Comment: `KeyEvent` has a `VK_PASTE` constant (which works here @HovercraftFullOfEels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why listen for "pastes"? Why not simply use a DocumentListener added to the PlainDocument that is the JTextArea's "model"? This will notify you of **all** changes to the document regardless of source. If you want to prevent modification of the document as you listen then use a DocumentFilter.  Regardless, if this is a Swing GUI, you probably shouldn't be using KeyListeners at all.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for anyways. Works perfectly with all input, pasting and dragging in included. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`KeyEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) has a constant value named [`VK_PASTE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_PASTE) which can be used inside of [`KeyListener#keyPressed(KeyEvent e)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html#keyPressed%28java.awt.event.KeyEvent%29):

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_PASTE:
      // do stuff when a paste occurs
  }
}
```

There are also `VK_CUT` and `VK_COPY`, which might be helpful. All of these should be system independent as well, according to the doc.

Comment: Text can be pasted without use of key strokes, so this will not capture all events. I'm still not sure where the OP is going with his question, and may never know as he seems to refuse to clarify it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Apparently, `VK_PASTE` recognizes the moused option as well.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it should work, but it isn't firing. I was having an issue with my listeners updating one input late, but even with a simple println it does not fire.

Comment: @UnstoppableDave You have to add `KeyListener` to the GUI. `your_component.add(your_keyListener)`;

Comment: @Jon I have other key listeners on actual keystrokes working fine, it's just the paste command that isn't firing the event.

Comment: @Hover I have an interface that updates a second text field as the user is entering text in the first. I want to be able to update that second area on a paste event as well.

Comment: @UnstoppableDave: then you probably want to use a DocumentListener, not a KeyListener. Please see my answer.